Stripe Error (I think): "No secret provided"
We had Stripe working, and then we did stuff in WordPress (moving a staging site to production), and now we're getting Stripe errors that we can't make sense of.
When we try to submit a credit card on a contribution page, we get a Stripe error like:
"Sorry an error occurred and your request was not completed. (Error ID: Taxn-0HpC-Ruwx)"
When we use the Pay Later option on an event registration page, we get: "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
No secret provided"
I've Googled "No secret provided" and I don't see anything related.
We also updated the Stripe extension. Not sure if that contributed to this or not.
WordPress 6.5.5
CiviCRM 5.76.2
Stripe Extension 6.11.2

Update: even when I disable all payment processors and uninstall the Stripe extension, when I try the online registration for a paid event (using the Pay Later option), I still get the "No secret provided" error.

So this actually didn't have anything to do with Stripe, CiviContribute, or WordPress. Apparently there's a bug in the Form Protection (reCaptcha) extension that was causing these errors. When I disabled the Form Protection extension, things worked as expected. See this thread for more details: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/5nh3ffsnopfcd8xxdhwsk36z4y

Patch available via https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31020 and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5421
